# How to move GitLab CI/CD Runner Executor on another disk?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a self-hosted GitLab CI/CD with a Docker Executor and I would like to know if it's possible to add a disk and configure it to store the Executor data (for example the Docker images or the jobs' artifacts).

I have gone through the Docker Executor documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) but it doesn't seem to describe how to configure the Executor to store its data on a particular disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build and cache folder to store your artifacts or exported stuff (yaml, conf, bin...) You can check this part https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-builds-and-cache-storage.

By default the Docker executor  stores all builds in

```
/builds/<namespace>/<project-name>
```

and all caches in `/cache` (inside the container) .

You can overwrite the /builds and /cache directories by defining the builds_dir and cache_dir options under the [[runners]] section in config.toml.

Otherwise, you can upload it in other cache location (s3,object, url...)